# I have website in asp .net currently online but its database become corrupted every time after new enteries

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-injection

In my website which is online local directory become corrupt when i put it on server. table in database got html tag but i dont change anything
enteries become like
Name
A Suresh

or different html tags

**is it sql injection??**
my website runs smoothly on localhost but when i put it online all enteries become corrupted after some time of updation.

```
 protected void b1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Byte[] bytes = null;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ToString());
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into dbocontent values(@image_name, @image_path, @firm_name, @phno, @address, @work_detail, @email, @website, @location, @city, @contact_person, @mob_no, @reciept_no, @opening_hours, @estblish, @deal, @status, @deal_duration, @deal_name, @deal_description, @category, @sub_category1, @sub_category2, @sub_category3, @phno2)", con);




        if (FileUpload2.HasFile)
        {
            string Extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload2.FileName);
            if (Extension.ToLower() != ".gif" && Extension.ToLower() != ".png" && Extension.ToLower() != ".jpg" && Extension.ToLower() != ".jpeg") { ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert('Invalid Image Format');", true); }
            else { string Pathname = "uploadimages/" + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName); string Filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName); cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image_name", Filename); cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image_path", Pathname); FileUpload2.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/uploadimages/" + FileUpload2.FileName)); }
        }

        else { ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert('pls select a file to upload');", true); }

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firm_name", txtfirmname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phno", txtphone.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtaddress.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@work_detail", txtworkdetail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtemail.Text);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@website", txtwebsite.Text);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", txtlocation.Text);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact_person", txtcontact_person.Text);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mob_no", txtmob.Text);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reciept_no", txtreciept.Text);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@opening_hours", txtopeningtime.Text);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estblish", txtestblish.Text);

           // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sub_sub_category", ddlsubsubcat.SelectedItem.Text);


           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deal", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "Yes")
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", txtstatus.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deal_duration", txtdealtime.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deal_name", txtdealname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deal_description", txtdes.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deal_duration", "");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deal_name", "");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deal_description", "");

        }
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", ddlcategory.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sub_category1", ddlsubsubcat1.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sub_category2", ddlsubsubcat2.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sub_category3", ddlsubsubcat3.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phno2", txtphno2.Text);




        string[] queryString3 = new string[22];
        queryString3[0] = txtfirmname.Text;
        queryString3[1] = txtphone.Text;
        queryString3[2] = txtaddress.Text;
        queryString3[3] = txtworkdetail.Text;
        queryString3[4] = txtemail.Text;
        queryString3[5] = txtwebsite.Text;
        queryString3[6] = txtlocation.Text;
        queryString3[7] = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text;
        queryString3[8] = txtcontact_person.Text;
        queryString3[9] = txtmob.Text;
        queryString3[10] = txtreciept.Text;
        queryString3[11] = txtopeningtime.Text;
        queryString3[12] = txtestblish.Text;
        queryString3[13] = txtstatus.Text;
        queryString3[14] = txtdealtime.Text;
        queryString3[15] = txtdealname.Text;
        queryString3[16] = txtdes.Text;
        queryString3[17] = ddlcategory.SelectedItem.Text;
        queryString3[18] = ddlsubsubcat1.SelectedItem.Text;
        queryString3[19] = ddlsubsubcat2.SelectedItem.Text;
        queryString3[20] = ddlsubsubcat3.SelectedItem.Text;
        queryString3[21] = txtphno2.Text;
      //  queryString3[19] = txtfirmname.Text;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(queryString3[0]))
        {
            List<string> y = queryString3.ToList<string>();
            y.RemoveAll(p => string.IsNullOrEmpty(p));
            queryString3 = y.ToArray();

            if (CheckSqlInjection(queryString3))
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/error.htm");
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                // c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", txtcategory.Text);
            }

        }
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString(), false);

        reset();

        con.Close();

    }
```

**// this is front end**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Admin Panel/MasterPage2.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="content.aspx.cs" Inherits="Admin_Panel_Default2" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <div class="cantant_right_text">
<%--<form id="form1" runat="server">--%>

<h1>Add New User</h1><br />

<table class="tabl">


    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbcategory" Text="Category"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcategory" runat="server" Height="35px" Width="253px"></asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label4" Text="Select Sub Category 1"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlsubsubcat1" Height="30px" Width="253px" 
                ></asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text="Select Sub Category 2"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlsubsubcat2" Height="30px" Width="253px" 
                ></asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label3" Text="Select Sub Category 3"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlsubsubcat3" Height="30px" Width="253px" 
                ></asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>

    </tr>



    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbfirmname" Text="Firm Name"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtfirmname" placeholder="Enter Firm Name"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
         <%--   <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtfirmname" ValidationExpression="^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$" runat="server" ErrorMessage="No Special Keys" BackColor="Red"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator></td>--%>
        <td>

        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbphone" Text="Phone Number"></asp:Label>

        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtphone" placeholder="Enter Phone Number"></asp:TextBox>
         <%--   <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" ControlToValidate="txtphone" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]+$" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Only Numeric Keys" BackColor="Red"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>--%>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbaddress" Text="Address"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtaddress" placeholder="Enter Address"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbworkdetail" Text="Work Detail"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtworkdetail" placeholder="Enter Work Detail"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbemail" Text="Email"></asp:Label>

        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtemail" placeholder="Enter Email"></asp:TextBox>
          <%--  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator4" ControlToValidate="txtemail" ValidationExpression="^[\w-\.]{1,}\@([\da-zA-Z-]{1,}\.){1,}[\da-zA-Z-]{2,6}$" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Email not valid" BackColor="Red"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>--%>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbwebsite" Text="Website Name"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtwebsite" placeholder="Enter Website Name"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblocation" Text="Location"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtlocation" placeholder=" Enter Location"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbcity" Text="City"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" Height="33px" Width="254px">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbcontact_person" Text="Contact Person"></asp:Label>



        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtcontact_person" placeholder="Enter Contact Person"></asp:TextBox>
            <%-- <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator5" ControlToValidate="txtcontact_person" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z]+$" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Only Alphabets" BackColor="Red"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>--%>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbmob_no" Text="Mobile Number"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtmob" placeholder="Enter Mobile Number"></asp:TextBox>
           <%--  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator6" ControlToValidate="txtmob" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]+$" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Only Numeric Keys" BackColor="Red"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>--%>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbreciept" Text="Reciept Number"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtreciept" placeholder="Enter Reciept Number"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbopeningtime" Text="Opening Hours"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtopeningtime" placeholder="Enter Opening Hours"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbestblish" Text="Estblish In"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtestblish" placeholder="Enter Estblish Year"></asp:TextBox>
           <%--  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator7" ControlToValidate="txtestblish" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]+$" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Only Numeric Keys" BackColor="Red"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>--%>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbdeal" Text="Deal"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="26px" Width="253px" 
                onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                AutoPostBack="True">
                <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <%--<tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label14" Text="Firm Name"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox14" placeholder="Enter Firm Name"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>--%>


    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbstatus" Text="Status"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtstatus" placeholder="Enter Status"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbdealtime" Text="Deal Duration"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtdealtime" placeholder="Enter Duration"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbdealname" Text="Deal Name"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtdealname" placeholder="Enter Deal Name"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbdealdescription" Text="Deal Description"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtdes" placeholder="Enter Description"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb2" Text="Phone Number 2"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtphno2" placeholder="Enter Phone Number 2"></asp:TextBox>
            <%--<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator8" ControlToValidate="txtphno2" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]+$" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Only Numeric Keys" BackColor="Red"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>--%>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Upload"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload2" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
         <td>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="b1" Text="Submit" 
                 style="margin-top:15px; width:255px; height:40px; color:White; background-color:#04579f; font-size:20px;" 
                 onclick="b1_Click"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

</div>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: What kind of this website is ? I mean is it open for public ?

Comment: As you said, **got html tag but i dont change anything** there's a chance of SqlInjection, more what you can do is, verify in which table you're getting such **HTML Tags** and verify screen related to that table.

Comment: Are you using sqlparameters to prevent sql injection? Are you using HtmlEncode (in your app) before saving to database? And using HtmlDecode (in your app) after pulling it out of database? Are you using varchar or nvarchar to save the HTML text?

Comment: its just dial like website for my city only

Comment: @dotnetN00b thanks to be there for my post. Noe it is the way that i am using to insert data please try to detect the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comment above, here is what your code should look like or be similar to.

```
    using System;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.WebUtility;

    public void SaveHTML(string htmltext)
    {
        string encodedHtmlText = HtmlEncode(htmltext);

        using (SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("sp_SaveHTMLText", sqlConn))
        {
            sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlcmd.CommandTimeout = 3600;

            SqlParameter eht = new SqlParameter("htmltext", encodedHtmlText);

            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(eht);

            sqlConn.Open();

            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        sqlConn.Close();
    }

    public string GetHTML(int htmlId)
    {
        string decodedHtmlText = String.Empty;

        using (SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetHTMLText", sqlConn))
        {
            sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlcmd.CommandTimeout = 3600;

            SqlParameter eht = new SqlParameter("htmlId", htmlId);

            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(eht);

            sqlConn.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader dr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        decodedHtmlText = HtmlDecode(dr["HtmlString"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        sqlConn.Close();

        return decodedHtmlText;
   }
```

NOTES:

- sp_SaveHTMLText and sp_GetHTMLText are the name of stored procedures.
- The while loop in GetHTML assumes that there will be only one record returned when calling sp_GetHTMLText.
- Also it is assumed that the column in the table where you are saving this to is either varchar or nvarchar.
- Since your tags say **asp.net-mvc**, I'm assuming you're using C#.
- Please see: [DotNetPerls - HtmlEncode](http://www.dotnetperls.com/htmlencode-htmldecode) and [SO - Storing HTML in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772897/storing-html-in-sql-server).

Comment: hii, i am not saving any html tag in my database. My database stores the information of local market that is also inserted by me it contains name, type , location ,contactno etc but not any html tag. I dont use sql parameters just inline sql query for fetching data.

Comment: You'll have to provide some sample code so we can better help you. Also, even if you are using inline sql, you should still be using sqlparameters.

Comment: hii, sorry for late reply

Comment: when i saw page source of my website i got following code in html                                          <div class="aspNetHidden">

 <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="788A752E" />
 <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEdAAl2aLMyBrtZwtIhwOWVr3iuho5JVALYeYSfp3s4DGVYsnIb18NOQZ6HqJweRbvL2fLAhygaqISv1ZMChneWRAbBYK5iiIoNKOUaiMrDAS0JTVl5WZ5pzF4Xl93SurYli0qLKQOQyDDn2/TzRYhe5udLu3S8pWYO1BhvsosazapYPZ9UXI7RwI+ukRHnd+AlDZ7i6zc75pMyWjogNy0+nYe6IPyMsg==" />
</div>

Comment: but i dont put this kind of stuff

Comment: We don't need the page source. We need a sample of the code you are using to save the data and get the data.

Comment: SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ToString());
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand c = new SqlCommand("insert into city values(@city)", con);

        c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", txtcity.Text);
      
        c.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Please edit your original post and post the relevant code. Please provide the following: the code you use to save the data, the code you use to get the data (from database), and the code you use to put the data into your HTML.