# show html code stored in database

Tags: c#, html, sql, view

I am using mvc, c# and sql. And I try to bring html code from my database ( for example , code for tables), and to show it in my view.
This is my viewmodel:

```
viewmodel:

public string Color { get; set; }
public string body { get; set; }
public string style { get; set; }
```

it is my code from my controller

```
 entity db = new myentity();
var html = new htmlviewmodel();
html.body=db.getbody(); //gets html code for my view, for example, a table
html.style=db.getstyle(); //gets a css style for instance, mystyle
```

and it would be my view

```
this is your table:
@model.body 
<div style=@model.style> bla bla </div>
```

Can anyone help me to know how to store html in my database? and how to use the html in my view?

Comment: What's the problem? You're looking for `Html.Raw()`.  And you almost definitely have XSS holes.

Comment: @SLaks curious why almost definitely XSS simply because HTML is being pulled from a database?  Ebaneo store the html as VARCHAR(MAX) or NVARCHAR(MAX) depending on if you will have unicode characters.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772897/storing-html-in-sql-server

Comment: Do you have to store it in the database?  If not, you are aware this is going to cause you a whole host of problems if you need to tweak the HTML slightly.

Comment: @Matt: No; because the HTML is probably not trusted.

Comment: @SLaks probably not trusted because it is being stored in a database and the source is currently unknown.  so outside world/user form very vunerable to XSS but inside version control or something should not be as susceptible.....My guess you probably have a point just seemed like a pretty big assumption from the little bit of detail in his question so I was curious if I was missing something.

Comment: This is handled server side, so it won't cause a XSS issue as the client will not know where the raw HTML came from, be it a view, database or other.

Comment: @Jay1b I had the same thought but what is the source of the HTML?  If a user form or WYSIWYG then you never know.

Comment: @Jay1b: That doesn't matter; XSS is just about HTML under an attacker's control.

Comment: thanks for taking your time, this html is generated by me, and is stored in a varchar(max) datatype. @slaks what kind of holes? I do not know about xss

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: thanks! well..once I use nvarchar (max) how am I supossed to proceed?  I mean, in my view what should I use?@Html.Raw?can anyone give me an example? thanks

Answer (score -1):

Are you getting the  to display? Can you see the  in the served page (inspect the HTML)?

**EDITED: [Storing HTML in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772897/storing-html-in-sql-server) for information on how to store HTML in SQL Servers**

Comment: sorry, perhaps I did not explain well, I wanted to know in what format should I store html, and how to call it and display in my view

Comment: Okay well then Matt answered your question then. if you go to that link, it tells you to use VARCHAR(MAX) or NVARCHAR(MAX).