# Type clash: image is incompatible with varchar(max)

Tags: python, html, sql-server, types, pyodbc

I would like to save html in SQL Server.

From the discussions I have seen in stackoverflow ([Storing HTML in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772897/storing-html-in-sql-server)), the recommendation is to use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` or `VARCHAR(MAX)`

However, when I try to save html in the `VARCHAR(MAX)` Or `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column, it is giving me the following error:

> pyodbc.DataError: ('22018', '[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][SQL Server]Operand type clash: image is incompatible with
>   varchar(max) (206) (SQLExecDirectW); [22018] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)')

How can the issue be resolved?

Comment: Need to see your code. For whatever reason your code is generating a parameter of type `image`

Comment: It seems the parameter data type (image) is incorrect. Also, you are using the old `SQL Server` ODBC driver, which is unaware of data types introduces since SQL 2000.

Comment: Datatype of the "html" column is varchar(max)

here's a snippet of the code
document = urlopen(url, context=ctx)

html = document.read()
cur.execute('''Update dbo.Pages SET html=? WHERE url=?''', (html, url ) )

here's the error message:

cur.execute('''Update dbo.Pages SET html=? WHERE url=?''', (html, url ) )
pyodbc.DataError: ('22018', '[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Operand type clash: image is incompatible with varchar(max) (206) (SQLExecDirectW); [22018] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)')

Comment: would it help if i use "soup" or "testhtml" as the data source instead of "html"?

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
testhtml = memoryview(html)

Comment: i installed the ODBC Driver version 17

Comment: cur.execute('''Update dbo.Pages SET html=? WHERE url=?''', (html, url ) )
pyodbc.DataError: ('22018', '[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Operand type clash: image is incompatible with varchar(max) (206) (SQLExecDirectW); [22018] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)')

Comment: error is the same

Comment: I am having the same issue using Driver=SQL Server and a None type is trying to be cast to an image on a geography field???? What is going on?

Comment: @Steve - The ancient `Driver=SQL Server` supports SQL Server 2000, while the geography type was introduced in SQL Server 2008. The driver does not know how to handle the geography data type because it did not exist when the driver was written.

Comment: @GordThompson what is the proper token to pass to use the most recent driver?

Comment: @Steve - Right now the latest version of msodbcsql is `DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server`. Of course, you'll need to [install it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) before you can use it.